# Sum of cos(x) to multiply of sen(x) in integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, physics

Good evening. Could you explain this step to me? Thanks.[image]

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1):

Creo que debería ser 
$$\cos^2\left(\frac{\omega_1 + \omega_2}{2}t\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{\omega_2 - \omega_1}{2}t\right)$$
en lugar de
$$\operatorname{sen}^2\left(\frac{\omega_1 + \omega_2}{2}t\right)\operatorname{sen}^2\left(\frac{\omega_2 - \omega_1}{2}t\right).$$

Comment: si creo que tiene que dar esa formula y que el resultado está equivocado. Gracias